# Putting links into text in Django

Tags: html, django

I have a notifications app that generates notifications for users. The notification class has to be really general, because notifications are generated by all sorts of different things.

My question is this: How do I insert links into the text of the notifications?

What I tried was this:

```
note = Notification(..., notification="""%s %s has accepted the task: <a href="/tasks/%d/">%s</a>.""" % (request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name, task.id, task.name), ...)
```

In retrospect, it's obvious this wouldn't work. 
How should I go about this?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Django is outputting the < and > characters as lt and gt

Comment: What output is are you getting which is undesirable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got will work fine, provided that when you output the Notification, Django doesn't escape it, either using the [`safe`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter in your template, or `mark_safe` somewhere in your view or model code.

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know about the safe filter.